# Asp.net Mvc: Ninject - IPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject, iprincipal

I was wondering how I could bind the IPrincipal to HttpContext.Current.User in Asp.net Mvc with Ninject.

Friendly greetings,

Pickels

Edit:

Not sure if it matters but I use my own CustomPrincipal class.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this without the need for a provider in your `NinjectModule`:

```
Bind<IPrincipal>()
  .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.User)
  .InRequestScope();
```

Note, I included `.InRequestScope()` to ensure that the value of the method is cached once per HTTP request.  I'd recommend doing so even if you use the provider mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Think I got it:

```
public class PrincipalProvider : IProvider
{
    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User;
    }

    public System.Type Type
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomPrincipal); }
    }
}
```

And in my NinjectModule I do:

```
Bind<IPrincipal>().ToProvider<PrincipalProvider>();
```

If this is wrong or not complete please let me know and I'll adjust/delete.

Comment: is it possible to persist the IProvider over different layers, including ones that do not reference the web?